# Using convert to covert multiple jpg files to pdf - pdf quality

Tags: linux, pdf, conversion, jpeg

I used the command

**convert *.jpg out.pdf**

to convert multiple jpg files to pdf. But the quality of the output pdf is very low. Is there a way I can increase the quality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
convert -compress jpeg -page WIDTHXHEIGHT single.jpg single.pdf
```

Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: except that this `-page` argument doesn't seem to have any effect for me. If yo ugive an example how to generate an `a3` and `a4` document, that would be really helpful, thank you.